# How would I calculate a force on a spring? Or more specifically the weight of an object that spring is supporting

Tags: springs

I am trying to create a simulation for car suspension and tyre physics and to do the tyre physics I need to know how much weight is over the friction point that is under the spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The force associated with springs is well described by Hooke's law. The spring force is given by,
$$ F = k x $$ 
where $F$ is the spring force, $x$ is the displacement of the spring from its original resting position, and $k$ is the spring constant in units of force per length.

Comment: Are we sure car suspension follows Hooke law?

Comment: The force associated with displacement of the suspension system can be modeled using Hooke's law and an equivalent spring stiffness constant. If you are concerned with the dynamics of the suspension system, you would be dealing with linear differential equations of the form, $m d^2y/dx^2 + c dy/dx + k_{eq} x = f(t)$, where $k_{eq}$ would be an equivalent spring stiffness of the system, and the product $k_{eq} u$ is the force associated with displacement of the system (i.e. Hooke's law).

Comment: I mean that the relationship between spring deformation and spring force can be nonlinear. In other words the spring constant k can change with the deformation. Maybe there are reasons for car suspension to become progessively stiffer (not sure, it's not my field) with deformation.

Comment: I have never heard of non-linear suspension systems. The inherent nature of a non-linear spring mass system is chaotic. It wouldn't make sense to have a non-linear spring constant unless you were in fact yielding the material in the spring, which would defeat the purpose of the spring in the first place.

Comment: Nonlinearity can be geometrical, not only due to yielding. As an example,  leaf springs, which are commonly used in vehicle suspension systems become progressively stiffer with deformation because their deformed shape becomes more effective to transfer the vertical forces (their stiffness increases).

Comment: Even leaf springs are modeled with an effective/equivalent constant spring stiffness $k_{eq}$ simply because the deflection is small in comparison to the overall length of the bars. Why exactly do you wan't to model the spring stiffness with a nonlinear $k$? That is very rare in modeling, especially in the case of practical problems like car suspension. For instance, even the higher fidelity modeling of vehicle suspension systems use linear dynamics but with more degrees of freedom.

Comment: @cent As an example, the single degree of freedom dynamic modeling of a cantilever beam uses a constant spring stiffness. Is the beam stiffness properties dependent on the overall deflection of the beam at the tip? Obviously, but because the deflection is usually small in relation to the overall length of the beam, the stiffness is taken as $k_{eq} = 3EI/L^3$, where $E$ is the modulus of elasticity, $I$ is the moment of inertia of the cross section, and $L$ is the overall length of the cantilever beam. Hence, the dynamics of the beam is modeled as simple spring-mass system.

Comment: A suspension will become nonlinear at the limits of travel, say when it's compressed to the point where the limit bumper comes into play, but over the normal range of operation, it's linear.

Comment: I admit vehicle simulation is not my field. I just wanted to raise awareness for the op and others reading this, that Hooke law is not universal. Nonlinear dynamics are trully computationally hard but the choice to do it or not depends on the situation. If you want a vehicle model it is overkill, but when you are designing the components of the suspension maybe it is not. Of course anyone with this task should know better already.

Answer (score 0):

The weight supported by each spring will depend on how the weight is distributed by the vehicle.  Most vehicles are slightly heavier at the front so, a 60:40% or 55:45% distribution would be a good approximation for most cars.  Sports cars get closer to an even split.  Then, you would subtract the weight of the tyre and supporting axle, brake, etc. since that weight is not supported by the spring.